# Racecar Wrap Job

Tags: materials, uv

I need to change the wrap up on this vehicle. Here's the UV map and the associated material, which is in a JPEG. How can I secure the outline of the UV map of the vehicle so I have an easier time editing the JPEG? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Edit->Preferences.  Select Add-ons.  Search for *UV*.  Enable the add-on *Import-Export: UV Layout*.

This will allow you to export the UV map as a separate file that you can then import in your drawing program and use as a layer.  Just remember not to include that layer when you save your edited image.

You can find [instructions for the add-on](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/addons/import_export/mesh_uv_layout.html) in the manual, but basically, when you're in the UV editor you'll have a new entry under the UV menu "Export UV Layout".